# Why is unordered_multimap::equal_range Average case constant?

Tags: c++, time-complexity

I'm doing some review on `unordered_multimap` and i came across the `equal_range` function. I read [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/equal_range/) that the complexity for `equal_range` is average case constant, but worse case linear. How can the average case be constant? I would imagine the average case to be linear, especially if there are multiple values for a particular key in the `unordered_multimap`.

Thanks for taking your time to answer!

Comment: Time complexity here is referring to input size of the container, not the number of keys which match. For example, if 10 keys match in a container of a million keys, 10 iterations would still be constant-time as in, the amount of work doesn't scale linearly with the size of the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be wary of where you get your information from

From draft [N4567](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4567.pdf)

[associative.reqmts]

`std::set`, `std::map`, `std::multiset`, `std::multimap`

[image]

[unord.req]

`std::unordered_set`, `std::unordered_map`, `std::unordered_multiset`, `std::unordered_multimap`

[image]

Comment: `Be wary of where you get your information from` - Does that include you? ;) +1

Comment: @erip Absolutely, it even includes the standard at times :D

Comment: ironically, i got my information from cplusplus.com, but i think you clarified their explanation. Thanks man -

Comment: @SnG cplusplus is, or at least was widely considered quite a poor resource. You're usually better off with [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com).

Comment: What do you think `count`'s complexity should be?

Comment: @T.C. Sorry I was just confused by the complexity being defined in terms of `count` itself and the change from C++11 to C++14, I thought it might have been a copying error but this [defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2304) cleared it up for me.